# What is the cardinality of $\overline{\overline {\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of $\overline{\overline {\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}}}$

My professor's train of thought is as follows:

$\overline{\overline {\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}}} \geq \overline{\overline{\left\{1,2\right\}^\mathbb{N}}} = \overline{\overline{\left\{0,1\right\}^\mathbb{N}}} = c$

I am trying to understand this problem with the substitution property: if $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{\overline{C}}$, and $\overline{\overline{B}} = \overline{\overline{D}}$, then $\overline{\overline{B^{A}}}$ = $\overline{\overline{D^{C}}}$.

Going back to the example, I can see that $\overline{\overline{\left\{1,2\right\}^\mathbb{N}}} = \overline{\overline{\left\{0,1\right\}^\mathbb{N}}}$ if I let $\mathbb{N}$ be $A$ and $C$ and $\left\{1,2\right\}$  and $\left\{0,1\right\}$ be $B$ and $D$, respectively.

I'm trying to figure out how $\overline{\overline{\left\{0,1\right\}^\mathbb{N}}} = c$ by using the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. How can I go about doing so?

Comment: What do the lines mean?

Comment: Step One: Search the site for previously asked questions. Step Two: Find that all these questions were asked infinitely often before yours. Step Three: Pick one out and read the answers.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: That's an old notation for cardinality.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So they should be dropped from the title and from the first sentence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila don't you need some choice axiom to choose from an infinite collection of questions? :P

Comment: @Dylan: No, you only choose one.

Comment: You need choice so show that $\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0$.